# How to properly use pivot funciton to combine multiple values (or columns) into within one column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table that contains UPC, Month# and Week# these three main columns.
(screenshot below)

[image]

Is it possible to create a View or display the table that groups the week numbers into one column for each unique UPC so there would be that many rows displayed.
(example like this)

[image]

Do I need to use the pivot function with GROUP BY GROUPING SETS to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use STUFF and FOR XML for this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38788)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (RecordID INT, UPC BIGINT, MonthNumberOnPromo INT, WeekNumberOnPromo INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1  , 2529230005 , 1   , 1)  , (2  , 2529230005 , 2   , 6),
(3  , 2529230005 , 3   , 11) , (4  , 2529230005 , 4   , 15),
(5  , 2529230005 , 6   , 22) , (6  , 2529230005 , 7   , 27),
(7  , 2529230005 , 8   , 31) , (8  , 2529230005 , 9   , 35),
(9  , 2529230007 , 1   , 1)  , (10 , 2529230007 , 2   , 6),
(11 , 2529230007 , 3   , 11) , (12 , 2529230007 , 4   , 15),
(13 , 2529230007 , 6   , 22) , (14 , 2529230007 , 8   , 31),
(15 , 2529230007 , 9   , 35) , (16 , 2529230007 , 10   , 38),
(17 , 2529230007 , 12  , 51)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.UPC
          ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH ,  '1900' + RIGHT('00' 
                       + CAST(t.MonthNumberOnPromo AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) + '01') , 3)  AS [Month]
          ,'Yes' AS Value
          ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(WeekNumberOnPromo AS NVARCHAR(10))
                  FROM @TABLE
                  WHERE t.UPC = UPC
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                  .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [Week_List]
    FROM @TABLE t
    GROUP BY t.UPC
             ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH ,  '1900' + RIGHT('00' 
                        + CAST(t.MonthNumberOnPromo AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) + '01') , 3) 
    )t
PIVOT (MAX(Value)
       FOR [Month]
       IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])
      )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38788/0)**:

```
|        UPC |                WEEK_LIST | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR |    MAY | JUN |    JUL | AUG | SEP |    OCT |    NOV |    DEC |
|------------|--------------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|--------|-----|--------|-----|-----|--------|--------|--------|
| 2529230005 |    1,6,11,15,22,27,31,35 | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | (null) | Yes |    Yes | Yes | Yes | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2529230007 | 1,6,11,15,22,31,35,38,51 | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | (null) | Yes | (null) | Yes | Yes |    Yes | (null) |    Yes |
```

Comment: Thank you, M.Ali.
May I know what does '19000101' mean?

Comment: since you have months stored as Integer values, I could have used Case statement too but I converted that Month number into a mock date value and then used `DATENAME()` function to get the name of month from that date value.

Comment: Also please look closer I have changed the way I was converting Integer month into date as first if it was 12 month it would have added 12 months in 19000101 and would return January from date value of 19010101